# How to remove get_subscription_totals_template function from the hook woocommerce_subscription_totals_table

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I want to replace the Subscription Totals given by the WooCommerce Subscriptions with my plugins version of Subscription Totals table.

In the WooCommerce Subsciptions plugin's `class-wcs-template-loader.php` there is a line that loads the subscription total template

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_subscription_totals_table', array( __CLASS__, 'get_subscription_totals_template' ) );
```

I'm trying to remove the function from the hook and replace it my own version of template. But it is not working!

I've written the following in my plugin file

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_subscription_totals_table', array( __CLASS__, 'get_subscription_totals_template' ) );
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Put this instead:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_subscription_totals_table', array( 'WCS_Template_Loader', 'get_subscription_totals_template' ) );
```